# Why is the closure of a set not the same as its limit points?

Tags: general-topology, limits

I'm getting confused about the notion of a limit point in a topological space.

In my notes I have:

> If $L(A)$ is the set of all limit points of $A$, then $L(A)\subseteq
>  \text{closure}(A)$, but the sets are not necessarily equal.

But the definition given is:

- $x\in X$ is a limit point of $A$ if there is a sequence $x_n\in A$ the
  converges to $x$

Doesn't this imply $A\subseteq L(A)$, so $L(A)=\text{closure}(A)?$

Another set of notes I have has:

- $x\in X$ is a limit point of $A$ if any open neighbourhood $U$ containing $x$ has $U\bigcap A\neq\emptyset$

Again don't we have $A\subseteq L(A)?$

I can't see where my logic is going wrong...

Comment: There can be a point in A that is not a limit point of A.  i.e. there could be some isolated point, such that the open ball around it contains no other points.  That would be in the closure of A and not in the set of limit points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your logic is fine: both of those definitions do imply that $A\subseteq L(A)$. The problem is that those definitions are non-standard. The usual definitions are as follows. First, for metric spaces:

> $x\in X$ is a limit point of $A$ if there is a sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $A\color{red}{\setminus\{x\}}$ that converges to $x$.

In other words, the constant sequence at $x$ isn’t allowed. And for topological spaces in general:

> $x\in X$ is a limit point of $A$ if any open nbhd $U$ containing $x$ has $U\cap\big(A\color{red}{\setminus\{x\}}\big)\ne\varnothing$.

That is, each open nbhd of $x$ must contain some point of $A$ **other than** $x$.

For example if $X=\Bbb R$, and $A=\{0\}\cup(1,2)$, $L(A)=[1,2]$, which does not contain $0$: $0$ is not a limit point of $A$ because no sequence in $(1,2)$ converges to it (first definition), or because $(-1,1)$ is an open nbhd of $0$ disjoint from the rest of $A$ (second definition).

Answer (score 1):

Check the definition of limit point again. An important part of the definition is that $x_n\neq x$, and the $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$, but without $x$ itself (rather, a deleted neighborhood of $x$). The reason this is important is that we do not want isolated points to be limit points. For example, in the set $[0,1]\cup\{2\}$, the point $2$ should not be a limit point.